# What is the order of function execution with jQuery on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
$(function () {
    $(".items").on('click', 'a', function () {
        //nothing gets executed here, alert wont come
        alert("doesn't work")
    }, function () {
        //this function gets executed
        alert("works")
    });
});
```

Why doesn't first function work, Is `.on()` not supposed to work this way? What is my alternative?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?  I'm guessing your third parameter(the first function) is getting passed in as the data into the handler. http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kjyac/)

Comment: The docs are clear on how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on()` does not have multiple handlers like `hover()` does. The third parameter is for data to be passed into the handler. I suppose this would be an option if you wanted to use the `data` param as a callback for the handler. This will call both of your functions: http://jsfiddle.net/M4x4u/1/

```
$(function () {
    $(".items").on('click', 'a', function () {
        //nothing gets executed here, alert wont come
        alert("doesn't work")
    }, function (e) {
        //this function gets executed
        alert("works")
        e.data();
    });
});
```

Comment: You pretty much answered by question, but why does second function get executed first.

Comment: The second function is the handler, the first function is data that gets passed into the handler. In the above example, I am passing data (third parameter) into the handler (fourth parameter) and then calling it from within it.

Comment: but this works for just first Iteration

Comment: What do you mean by "first iteration"? Nothing is getting iterated, do you mean if you click the link twice? It should be the same, works the same for me on first and second click.

Comment: Thanks, It works. Are there other function like toggle that take multiple handlers? to name a few?

Comment: That sounds like another/separate question, but I'm not sure what you are looking for. You can call several functions from within the handler if you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/M4x4u/2/... or add more `on('click'`s

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know which jquery methods dont take multiple handlers. e-g .on and ????

Comment: Most of them don't, hover does because it handles both mouse in and out http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 2):

Your second function becomes the event handler. Your first function is getting passed as data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're confusing `on` with `toggle`.

```
$(function() { 
  $(".items").on('click',  'a', function() { 
    alert("this works now")
  });
});
```